# How to know sub version check out date

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04 as my operating system & Subversion as my version control system. Currently I'm working with SVN branch & I need to know the date and time which that branch checkout. When if type svn info in terminal if gives only Last Changed Date.

[image]

How do I know my working branch checkout date and time.

Comment: Wouldn´t it be enough to get the date and time when you created the checkout directory?

Answer (score 0):

Subversion does not track checkouts as they are not repository-modifying events.

The timestamp of when the working copy directory on your local filesystem (not `svn info`) will be your best clue as to when you performed the checkout. However, that's not the best indicator of the content/state of your working copy - that is best determined from what you already have, `svn info`.